# Does my Indonesian friend need to prepare the visa for her 8 year old son (US passport holder) to visit Slovakia and the Czech Republic?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, czech-republic, indonesian-citizens, slovakia

My friend has an Indonesian passport and US green card and lives in the US.
We would like to visit Slovakia and the Czech Republic this coming summer.

As she is Indonesian I believe that she needs to get a visa from both countries, then question...
Does her 8 year old son also need a visa when he travels with her?  He has both an Indonesian and a US passport.

Answer (score 13):

**No**: since her son is a US citizen, **he does not need a visa** for the **Schengen Area**.

As for your friend, Slovakia and Czechia are both members of the [Schengen Area](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Travelling_around_the_Schengen_Area), so she only needs to apply for one visa from the country she will spend the most time in.  Once granted, she can travel around the entire Schengen Area freely.

Comment: To be clear, the son can only travel without a visa if he _uses_ the US passport.

Comment: Perhaps a clarification might be good: The visa application for the Indonesian citizen will contain an itinerary covering both Slovakia and the Czech Republic. After it is granted, the itinerary may be *adjusted*, e.g. with different transit airports. It is not permitted to completely change plans and go just anywhere (say to Greece with a visa for Iceland).

Comment: @o.m. according to https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/visa-service/-/231202#content_1 "Persons granted a short-stay visa with no territorial restrictions (category “C” visa) by a Schengen country may, for the duration of the visa’s validity, stay and travel freely in the territory of any other Schengen country." Are you talking about a different visa category where travel restrictions would apply?

Comment: @Dreamer, it is this visa. The thing is that one **may** adjust the itinerary after it is granted, even adding or skipping entire countries, but one **must not** misrepresent the itinerary in the application, and so one **should not** give the impression that the itinerary was a lie by gross changes afterwards, unless there is an obvious explanation for them. One could write in the application, "I'll go to a random selection of Schengen states in a random order," and if that visa is granted one can do just that, but such an application is unlikely to be granted.